# fantasy series 80s - ghouls come out at night and people turn into trees?

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

This was a series of books I read in the 80s, part fantasy/horror, where the world has been inhabited by spirits/ghouls that can only exist in the dark. If they touch you, you die instantly. People have retreated behind walls and in fortresses and have to keep fires lit at all times, I think there was also some weird thing happening where people were turning into trees or something?!

would be nice for my kids to read them!!